# as_json in rails unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to return only email  in JSON  body and employee profile but I have a syntax error

I do this

```
render json: @submittings.as_json(include: {user: {include: :employee} })
```

```
[
    {
        "id": 21,
        "job_id": 27,
        "user_id": 39,
        "created_at": "2020-06-17T07:30:00.454Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-06-17T07:30:00.454Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 39,
            "email": "employ1@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2020-06-17T07:14:50.063Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-17T07:14:50.063Z",
            "auth_token": "WEszR9zrn3RzQQEXpfVh",
            "employee": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "employee one profile",
                "jobtybe": null,
                "jobcategory": null,
                "address": null,
                "salary": null,
                "Gander": null,
                "Qualifcation": null,
                "mobile": null,
                "Degree": null,
                "Indestry": null,
                "Exprense": null,
                "created_at": "2020-06-17T07:26:28.400Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-17T07:26:28.400Z",
                "user_id": 39
            }
        }
    }
]
```

but I need to return only email in user I try this but I have a syntax error

```
render json: @submittings.as_json(include: {user: {only: :email}, include: {employee:} })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ employee: }` it's invalid as a Hash. As you're trying to create a Hash with no value.

Try replacing it with just the symbol:

```
@submittings.as_json(include: { users: { only: :email, include: :employee } })
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<Submitting: